# Preparing wordpress plug in download link

Tags: html, wordpress, hide, show

There are file links to download on the site I made. I want the person who opens that page on the site to count down for 10 seconds, for example, and show the links when this time expires, with a text like "Preparing the download link". I couldn't find a plug-in that does this. can you help if you have or how can i do this with div show hide.
Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This is a plugin I wrote specifically for my website, demo you can click on the link to see it directly, if you like it, you can download and use it:
Link: https://github.com/itsmeit268/preplink

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34423886)